# Android Translucent Status Bar Issues

Tags: android, android-layout

I want to display an website on and iphone but I want the status bar to show transparent on top of the website. Right it displays a bark/black color.

I have read and tried a hundred of solutions online and read as much documentation about it as possible. [Android Status Bar](https://developer.android.com/training/material/theme.html#StatusBar) But still I cannot get it to work.

**styles.xml**

```
<resources>

    <!-- Base application theme. -->
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar">
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>

        <item name="android:windowTranslucentNavigation">false</item>
        <item name="android:windowTranslucentStatus">true</item>
        <item name="android:statusBarColor">@android:color/transparent</item>
        <item name="android:navigationBarColor">@android:color/transparent</item>

        <item name="windowActionModeOverlay">true</item>
    </style>

</resources>
```

MainActivity.java

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

```
private WebView myWebview;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    myWebview = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.activity_main_webview);
    WebSettings settings = myWebview.getSettings();
    settings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    myWebview.loadUrl("http://www.google.com");
    myWebview.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());

}
```

}

Any idea what could I be doing wrong ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to change "android:windowTranslucentNavigation" to true.
And also set FLAG_LAYOUT_NO_LIMITS in your activity:

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) {
            Window w = getWindow();
            w.setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_NO_LIMITS, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_NO_LIMITS);
        }
```